# Can I Access Outlook Add-Ins Through Outlook.Application in my Code?

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin, outlook.application

I'm using `Outlook.Application` to send emails from my C# code.
I have this Voltage Encryption Add-In which allows you to "Send Secure" a message rather than the normal Send.

Can I use this Send Secure in my code? Is there some way to access add-ins?

I can loop through `Microsoft.Office.Core.COMAddIns` and see that it is there but cannot really do anything with these Add-Ins. Just see basic info about them.

There is an interface exposed by the `VoltageAdddIn` dll which has the "SendSecureButtonClicked(object ribbonControl)" method. Maybe I can use this somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the addin designer did not explicitly give you that ability, you can't. You can access COM addins through the `Application.COMAddins` collection (you can play with it in [OutlookSpy](http://www.dimastr.com/outspy/) - I am its author - click Application button, select COMAddins property, click Browse, go to the IEnumVariant tab)
If addin decides to expose its objects for external consumption, `COMAddin.Object` property will be `!= null`.

Comment: Well the object is null... But for those that aren't null how are they accessed? They just return a System.__ComObject which isn't particularly helpful.

Comment: You will need to know which particular interface they expose. If the object is IDispatch based and supports type info, OutlookSpy will show its properties and methods (select the Object property, click Browse).